# Predicate projection not working in parquet

Tags: parquet

First of all I am new to this forum and I am a novice in parquet and trying to understand the nitty gritty of it. Have written a java Map Reduce code to validate the predicate & column projection. Here is the challenge that I face which I need help from you experts.

Predicate Projection code:

```
    public static class PushDown implements UnboundRecordFilter {
    private final UnboundRecordFilter filter;
    public PushDown() 
    {
        filter = ColumnRecordFilter.column("Age",ColumnPredicates.equalTo(35));         
    }
    @Override
    public RecordFilter bind(Iterable<ColumnReader> readers) {
        return filter.bind(readers);
    }   
}
```

Invoking the predicate projection:

> AvroParquetInputFormat.setUnboundRecordFilter(job, PushDown.class);

Got Below Error:

```
Error: parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/parq/customer/wocomp/part-m-00000.parquet
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:241)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$Binding.getBinary(ColumnReaderImpl.java:118)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.getBinary(ColumnReaderImpl.java:417)
    at parquet.filter.ColumnPredicates$1.apply(ColumnPredicates.java:67)
    at parquet.filter.ColumnRecordFilter.isMatch(ColumnRecordFilter.java:72)
    at parquet.io.FilteredRecordReader.skipToMatch(FilteredRecordReader.java:80)
    at parquet.io.FilteredRecordReader.read(FilteredRecordReader.java:60)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:216)
    ... 12 more
```

Additional Info:

I am able to validate the Column Projection using below code and I could see [Results like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeg1T.png). which was like [this without column projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIUnA.png)

```
Schema projection = Schema.createRecord("AvgAge", "", "", false);
        List<Schema.Field> fields = new ArrayList<Schema.Field>();
        fields.add(new Schema.Field("Age", Schema.create(Schema.Type.LONG), "",""));
        projection.setFields(fields); 

        AvroParquetInputFormat.setRequestedProjection(job, projection);
```

Questions:

Q1. In above code, what needs to be corrected for filter push down to work?

Q2. I don't see much info in logs to validate projection. Could you help how we should be validating the filter/column projection?

Appreciate your time looking this and trying to help out. Thank you.